# vimscript buffer to get output of perl script

Tags: perl, buffer, vim

I'm trying to edit the copy-paste buffer:

I have the following command:

```
nmap gfb :let .shellescape(getreg('0'))=1<br>
```

that should have put the number `1` into the buffer, which is not happening.

how do i put the output of a perl script into a vimscript buffer?

Comment: very relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471175/vim-replace-word-with-contents-of-paste-buffer                                      @" is the copy-paste buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store 1 inside register 0:

```
:let @0 = 1
```

To do this in vimscript via perl:

```
function! Foo()
perl << EOF
    my $foo = 1;
    VIM::DoCommand(':let @0 = ' . $foo);
EOF
endfunction
```

Then you can call that function:

```
:call Foo()
```

Comment: This is totally in the direction, but i get the following error: E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: perl << EOF

Comment: the solution to the e319 error was to do: sudo apt-get install vim-full in the shell. but now the let doesn't work.

Comment: Just to be clear, you now have a vim with Perl support, which means the `perl` and `doperl` commands are now available to you. This won't change the other non-Perl stuff.

Answer (score 3):

To get the output of an external command into a vim buffer you use `system`:

```
:let @0 = system("/bin/ls")
:echo @0
```

I'm not sure how this relates to Perl exactly. You might want to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: okey so in order to get the output of a perl scrip i do: :let @0=system('perl /home/hermann/hi.pl')     ?

Comment: Something like that, yes. Of course `system` can be used anywhere you can use an expression - its not just for assignment. Try it and see!

Comment: :let @0=222 doesn't work anymore, i dont know why but it doesn't change what gets pasted when i press p. it used to though so im not sure whats going on.

Comment: the paste array is @", @0 is an array thats always changing and that was confusing me. it works now.

Comment: on a related note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579905/get-perl-script-output-into-vimscript

Comment: You really should spend some time experimenting and reading the vim docs. Your questions suggest you have some gaps in your understanding.