# get perl-script output into vimscript

Tags: perl, vim

I have tried the following:

```
:let @0 = system('perl /home/hermann/hi.pl')
:echo @0
```

Having hi.pl like this:

```
\#!/usr/bin/perl
exit(34);
```

But I dont get 34 into `@0`, I get nothing.

How do I return a value from a perl script to a vimscript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `:echo @0v` is just a typo that should be `:echo @0`, right?

Secondly, [system()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#system%28%29) in vimscript returns the standard output of the command not the command's return value. Your `let @0 ...` is equivalent to one of these in perl:

```
my $x = `perl /home/hermann/hi.pl`;
my $y = qx:perl /home/hermann/hi.pl:;
```

If you want the return value rather than the command's standard output, look at the [v:shell_error](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#v%3ashell_error) variable.