# How to copy a word and paste it over another word in Vim?

Tags: vim

I know how to copy a word, but I seem to overwrite what is in my clipboard because, when I try to copy over a word, it does not seem to be working.

To copy a word, I can use

```
bye
```

How to copy over a word?

Comment: Not sure if exact dupe, but comes close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471175/vim-replace-word-with-contents-of-paste-buffer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910215/9384511

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Perhaps you just want to do this:

```
viwp
```

which will visually select a new word, and paste over it.

Now, if you don't want to lose your register when doing this, you can also put in your vimrc:

```
xnoremap p pgvy
```

Comment: `xnoremap p pgvy` works great. `vep` is one keypress shorter than `viwp`, and does the same.

Comment: visual mode is great, but if you can do without it just as easily, with something like dwP, wouldn't that be better?

Comment: @nrz no way "it does the same",`vep` would only work the same way if cursor was at the beginning of the word. `viwp` works anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Copy the source word as usual (e.g., with `yiw`) and use

```
viw"0p
```

to paste over the destination word.

Since the `p` command in Visual mode (see `:help v_p`) does not alter
the numbered register `0` containing the text from the most recent
yank command, the same copied word can be pasted over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

Do this once:

`ciw<C-r>0`

Then to replace words always using the text you yanked do:

`.`

You can use search with it like this:

`/foo<Cr>`

`.n.n.n`

It works because:

`ciw` replaces inner word and

`<C-r>0` uses the most recently yanked register to replace it, which `.` then also uses.

Sadly, this does not work if you visually select text you wish to replace and use `.`.

Note that if you originally used visual selection to select the text to replace and did `c<C-r>0` then after that `.` will replace the same length of characters as was included in the visual selection.

Answer (score 2):

You could use register 0, which contains the just-overwritten "clipboard" text.  For your example, you could yank the text to paste, put the cursor somewhere in the word "bye", and type

`ciw` [cut in word; deletes the word under the cursor and goes to insert mode there]

`ctrl-r 0` [register 0; paste text from register 0]

You can see what's in all the registers with `:disp`.  As Daenyth says, you can yank into a particular register with `"x`[del/cut/yank command] and paste with `"xp` from command mode, or `ctrl-r x` from insert / replace.

Comment: I would say that you misunderstood the question. There is no mention of a word “bye”, just the vim normal command “bye” that is equivalent to “yiw”

Comment: @Benoit I see the `bye` as a command now. Regardless, my answer answers the correct question and is correct and properly informative.  The word to be pasted over is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a word it is put in the `"` register which is the default register for pasting, so when you delete the word you want to replace, it will take the previous word's place in the `"` register. However, the previous word will be in register `0`, the one before in `1` and so on – you can at any time see this by running `:reg` and see the registers' contents. So, to replace a word you can first copy the first word (`yiw`), then “change” the word you want to replace (`ciw`) and then insert from register `0` by hitting `ctrl-r`, `0`. (You could also first delete the word (`diw`) and then paste from register `0`: `"0p`.

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is to do it the other way around: first paste the new word, then delete the old one.

Comment: but I want to be able to paste it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can `y`ank into a register by prepending it with `"a` (where `a` is the name of the register). See [How to use vim registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers)

`b"aye`